# How to integrate a custom clang into Xcode 5?

Tags: xcode, clang

What is the best way to integrate a custom clang toolchain 
into Xcode5?
I tried to replace the standard clang with mine and got many errors about missing header files.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Apple patches Clang before it ships it with XCode, to accept certain options that the IDE uses when calling Clang.

You can always use a non-XCode project build system and build outside the IDE. Or use a different IDE.

If you still want to try, it sounds like you didn't configure Clang correctly to find all your system's header files. You need to configure Clang to use the ones you want using

```
--with-c-include-dirs
--with-cxx-include-dirs
```

or something like this. Inspect LLVM's `configure --help` output on the real options and what they should be, I can't seem to find any decent documentation currently.